# Is there any MongoDB handler for find event?

Tags: mongodb, event-handling, auditing

I want to know is there any `handler` or `trigger` kind of functionality exist in MongoDB which can help me to run my mongo command on `find` query?

Basically, I want to run specific set of Mongo queries on find query. You can say a listener on `find` query to run other mongo commands.

Other than that is there anything like `create a view from a remote database`, I know MongoDB provides creating a view from the same database but I want from the remote database?

I do not want any application level solution like any third party module or watcher script, I want something which is within the MongoDB itself like inbuilt function or any event handling.

I have tried `auditing` but, it only records the operation and all, does not provide any handler through which I can run my mongo commands like `Oracle providing in Fine-grained auditing`.

Any help related to this is appreciable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed you also posted an [exact duplicate of this question on DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168925/9345), which is probably more appropriate if you are asking about a database server feature rather than an application or development solution.

Comment: Yes true, Ok I will not post anything related to the database here. Thnks for information.